# How to make a method that checks if a number is mixed with 1 odd digit and the other even digit

Tags: java

i am new to java  and i built a method that checks if a number has following digits that 1 is odd or even and the followed digit is the opposite.
for example if a the number is 12121 the method supposed to return true;

here's the code

```
public static boolean isMix(int x)
{
    String s = Integer.toString(x);
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < s.length() || j < s.length(); i++, j++)
    {
        if (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(i)) % 2 == 0&& Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(j)) % 2 == 1
                || (Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(i)) % 2 == 1 && Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(j)) % 2 == 0))
            counter++;
    System.out.println(counter);
    }
    if (s.length() == counter)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply return `false` if the parity of the current digit is the same as the previous digit.

```
public static boolean isMix(int x){
    String s = Integer.toString(x);
    for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)) % 2 
           == Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i - 1)) % 2) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```